# symfony 2 - members can access login page again?

Tags: php, symfony

Question,

I have ldap login page for symphony2 that works well, i can login and it redirects to correct page, what bothers me is that, when i try to go to /login url yet again as user, i still can see login page/form, it does not redirect me to homepage?

After i login i can see i have role -> Roles    [ROLE_USER]

Any idea how to fix that?

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login,          roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/css/,           roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/js/,            roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/images/,        roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/,               roles: ROLE_USER }

firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    secured_area:
        pattern: ^/
        provider: app_users
        form_login_ldap:
            service: app.ldap
            dn_string: "cos"
            check_path: /login_check
            login_path: /login
            default_target_path: homepage
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /
            invalidate_session: false
            delete_cookies:
                a: { path: null, domain: null }
                b: { path: null, domain: null }
        anonymous: ~
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change firewalls settings as below

```
firewalls:
# disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
dev:
    pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
    security: false

secured_area:
    pattern: ^/
    provider: app_users
    form_login_ldap:
        service: app.ldap
        dn_string: "cos"
        check_path: /login_check
        use_forward: false
        login_path: /login
        default_target_path: homepage
    logout:
        path:   /logout
        target: /
        invalidate_session: false
        delete_cookies:
            a: { path: null, domain: null }
            b: { path: null, domain: null }
    anonymous: ~
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add the following in your loginAction()

```
if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('homepage'));
} else {
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('login'));
}
```